Mapstruct List to List: mapping element list position
I have to classes Source and Target, where Target has an additional field index, and I want to map a list of Source objects to a list of Target objects, where the index field is populated with the position of the corresponding Source object in the source list.
I have a working example utilizing guava:
List<Target> mapList(List<Source> sources) {
    return Streams.mapWithIndex(sources.stream(), (source, index) -> mapElement(source, (int) index)).toList();
}

abstract Target mapElement(Source source, int index);

Since I want to get rid of guava, I wonder if there is a mapstruct way of achieving the same functionality.
I was researching about mapstruct functionality, but I found that there is no documented way of achieving the result. Now maybe there is some trickery that does the job.

maybe you should just use a for-loop.

@julaine, yes that is possible, it actually was a solution before refactoring it to mapWithIndex. I just don't think its pretty.

If you don't really use index:
@Mapper
public interface Mapper {
    List<Target> map(List<Source> sources);
}

That's all

But I, quote: "... want to map a list of Source objects to a list of Target objects, where the index field is populated with the position of the corresponding Source object in the source list."

As Wladimir's answer states, if you don't need the index, you can simply use:
@Mapper
public interface ListMapper {
    List<Target> map(List<Source> sources);
}

Even without guava, if you didn't need the index, you could use:
List<Target> mapList(List<Source> sources) {
    return sources.stream().map(this::mapTarget).toList();
}

abstract Target mapTarget(Source source);

If you need the index for some reason, you could use:
List<Target> mapList(List<Source> sources) {
    return IntStream.range(0, sources.size())
        .mapToObj(index -> mapElement(sources.get(index), index))
        .toList();
}

abstract Target mapElement(Source source, int index);

No guava required. But if MapStruct is generating mapElement for you then presumably the index is not actually used.

But I, quote: "... want to map a list of Source objects to a list of Target objects, where the index field is populated with the position of the corresponding Source object in the source list.".
For the actual solution, I would rather zip the IntStream, so that there is no sources.get(index).

@GeorgBraun In that case you may want to look at this solution or the StreamEx library which can do something like what you need although it still uses List.get under the covers.
